# What does def method (parameter = None) mean?

Tags: python

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, lastname, firstname = None):
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.firstname = firstname
```

What does `firstname = None` in the second row mean?

Comment: That's the default value of `firstname`.

Comment: Did you read through the [Beginner's Guid](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) or another tutorial?

Comment: In this case it is the default value for `firstname`.  This is preferred to setting, for example, an empty string.  Setting a parameter's default to `None` is commonly used when a new mutable object is required.  If you set a default to a mutable object (like a list) then that same single object is reused throughout the life of the program.  Using `None` is a pythonic way of indicating that a new object is required.

Answer (score 10):

This allows you to call this function and omit that particular parameter. If you do omit it, it will default to the listed value of `None`. If you do pass a value, it will be used.

```
>>> def f(arg='a'):
...     print(arg)
...
>>> f()
a
>>> f('b')
b
```